# How to add preloader to website without manually show/hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader

On my website (MVC and web API) I have added a preloader for a better user experience purpose.

I have added the preloader at two points:

1. After Login, between the user is authenticated and the redirection to the homepage.
2. In every page that loads data from the server.

I did it with an image that I `show` when the page/data loads and I `hide` when the data is fully loaded.

```
<div id="dvReqSpinner" style="display: none;">
  <br />
  <center><img src="~/images/loading_spinner.gif" /></center>
  <br />
</div>
```

And with jquery I `show` and `hide` it:

```
$("#dvReqSpinner").show();
$("#dvReqSpinner").hide();
```

It's a little bit anoying to keep showing and hiding an image every time I need to load data (using an AJAX call to web API, authenticating the user etc.. - Every action that takes time and I want to show the user that something is "happening"), isn't there any "automatic" option to have a preloader on a website?

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: Define "every time I need to load data" - when is that happening, what events are triggering it? What code does it?

Comment: @Umamaheswaran Yes, I'm using jquery.

Comment: @Tomalak Please see my edited question and let me know if still not clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if its the case, but if you use jquery ajax to handle your requests, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
   // every time a request starts
   $("#dvReqSpinner").show();

}).ajaxStop(function() {
   // every time a request ends
   $("#dvReqSpinner").hide();

});
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to avoid showing the spinner for fast requests, i think this can make it work:

```
var delayms = 3000; // 3 seconds

var spinnerTimeOut = null;

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
   // for every request, wait for {delayms}, then show spinner

   if(spinnerTimeOut!=null){
      clearTimeout(spinnerTimeOut);
   }

   spinnerTimeOut = setTimeout(function(){  
      $("#dvReqSpinner").show();
   }, delayms);

}).ajaxStop(function() {
   // every time a request ends
   clearTimeout(spinnerTimeOut); // cancel timeout execution
   $("#dvReqSpinner").hide();


});
```

Give it a try. i couldn't test it -.-'

Comment: @hindmost, i dont think so. `ajaxSend()` is triggered every single request.. so if we have a bunch of simultaneous requests, it will be triggered for every one. Instead, if we use `ajaxStart()`, it will be called on the first request, and `ajaxStop()` on the latest one.

Comment: @Ramon-san, thanks for the edit! i hadn't noticed -.-'

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it and it worked nicely but is there anyway to avoid the preloader to appear if the data loading takes let's say less than 3 seconds? The problem is that it comes up even when the data loads immediately.

Comment: @user3378165, yes. use a timeout with 3 seconds in the `ajaxStart()` callback, then clear it at `ajaxStop()`

Comment: Thanks for your edit but it seems like it's now working, the image shows up even if it's less than 3 seconds.

Comment: try again. i changed it a bit

Comment: Thank you, it's working, just only one more question, is there any way to declare that on `page load` it will `show` immediately and for all other calls it will show up after 3 seconds?

Comment: Sure. Instead using `#dvReqSpinner` with `display:none` at beginning, let it visible and hide it when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

To show or hide a loading indicator in a single page app, I would add and remove a CSS class from the body:

```
#dvReqSpinner {
    display: none;
}

body.loading #dvReqSpinner {
    display: block;
}
```

and

```
$("body").addClass("loading");
$("body").removeClass("loading");
```

Primarily this would make the JS code independent on the actual page layout, so it's "nicer" but not really "less work".

To do it "automatically", I recommend abstracting your Ajax layer into a helper object:

```
var API = {
    runningCalls: 0,
    // basic function that is responsible for all Ajax calls and housekeeping
    ajax: function (options) {
        var self = this;

        self.runningCalls++;
        $("body").addClass("loading");

        return $.ajax(options).always(function () {
            self.runningCalls--;
            if (self.runningCalls === 0) $("body").removeClass("loading");
        }).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
    // generic GET to be used by more specialized functions
    get: function (url, params) {
        return this.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: params
        });
    },
    // generic POST to be used by more specialized functions
    post: function (url, params) {
        return this.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: params
        });
    },
    // generic POST JSON to be used by more specialized functions
    postJson: function (url, params) {
        return this.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    },
    // specialized function to return That Thing with a certain ID
    getThatThing: function (id) {
        return this.get("/api/thatThing", {id: id});
    }
    // and so on ...
};
```

so that later, in your application code, you can call it very simply like this:

```
API.getThatThing(5).done(function (result) {
    // show result on your page
});
```

and be sure that the low-level stuff like showing the spinner has been taken care of.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would you be able to explain me how the helper will help me with the preloader?

Comment: Read the code. It's fully functional. I even commented everything, but connecting the dots is your job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global ajax handlers for this.

This code will execute whenever you make an ajax request. all you have to do here is enable your spinner.

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
  $("#dvReqSpinner").show();
});
```

This code will execute once your ajax request succeeded. all you have to do here is enable your spinner.

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, request, settings ) {
   $("#dvReqSpinner").hide();
});
```

You can also use other global ajax function to handle things like showing a popup when a ajax request fails using **".ajaxError()"**

Below link will have details of all the other functions

https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/